# How to refresh a ListFragment's data?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Note: Please ignore the formatting in question detail.

I have defined a class named BulletFragment which extends ListFragment, it does not do much.
I have also defined a customadapter named ListViewAdapter which extends BaseAdapter and holds an ArrayList (I know I could have extended ListAdapter instead of BaseAdapter but it did not suit my needs). This is where most of the logic resides.

From my main activity I am adding the BulletFragment using getSupportFragmentManager().
This main activity has spinner at the action-bar. I want different data to be shown on fragment when I select different options from spinner at the top. I am able to gather correct data in the onNavigationItemSelected method. In this method I am creating a new instance of ListViewAdapter for every selection made using spinner and passing this instance to fragment's setListAdapter method. But the data in the fragment is not updated. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adapter.notifydatasetchanged() method. It will redraw the list based on data change in your adapter. More about it [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29)

Comment: This is what i am doing

 ListViewAdapter tempAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(bullets, Today.this, fragment);
 fragment.setListAdapter(tempAdapter);
 ((BaseAdapter)fragment.getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

But still no use :(

Comment: I dont have an editor right now but I guess you should do something like getActivity() instead of Today.this or something and same goes for notifyDagaSetChanged. Please try tempAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().